# Fingerprint lock in Asus

Tags: asus, fingerprint-reader

How can I setup fingerprint lock on Ubuntu 18.04 in my Asus Vivobook S X510UN model?

Answer (score 0):

Fingerprint lock works in Ubuntu 18.04 and can be seen under `setting->user` (provided you have fingerprint GUI or so) but not all fingerprint scanners are supported by Linux.

So unless someone creates a drive for the same, it's up to no good.